# Canvas and z-index

Tags: html, z-index, html5-canvas

I have the following HTML code:

```
<div class="reflect" style="width: 348px; height: 327px; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden; ">
    <img id="image" class="reflected" 
         src="http://domain.com/1-1.png" 
         style="display: block; border-top-width: 0px; border-right-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; border-left-width: 0px; border-style: initial; border-color: initial;">
    <canvas width="348" height="54" 
        style="display: block; border-top-width: 0px; border-right-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; border-left-width: 0px; border-style: initial; border-color: initial; margin-top: -50px;"></canvas>
</div>
```

I want the canvas element to appear below the IMG. Right now, the canvas is on top of the image, 50px part of it on top (see margin-top: 50px). I've tried setting z-index to each element with no success. Need your help in solving this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a look at `absolute` positing of elements and `z-index`

If you position the `img` absolutely, set the z-index, and then remove the `margin-top` from the canvas element, this should work.

Comment: so how come that without position absolute both overlap each other and the canvas is on top of the image layer

Comment: without any sort of logical positioning, html automatically just flows. 1 element after the next. why would it want to appear above without you telling it to?